# What did General Zod want from Lois Lane?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, character-motivation, man-of-steel

In *Man of Steel*, General Zod ordered to bring Lois Lane along with Superman on-board his ship. Why?

Comment: Because... plot.

Comment: Related question from Movies & TV [Why did Zod ask for Lois Lane to come on their spaceship?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11978/why-did-zod-ask-for-lois-lane-to-come-on-their-spaceship)

Comment: I cannot read this question without hearing Beavis and Butthead giggling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When both Clark and Lois leave Zod's ship safely, she tells him that she is sorry, that the Kryptonians had gotten into her head but Clark reassures her by saying that they did the same to him and asks her not to worry.

I believe this is the reason why Zod brought her into the ship. He already knew that Lois was important to Superman so he figured she would know something about the Codex (which he later found out to be false). He was hoping that by "getting into her head", he would find a clue of it's location.

It could be argued that Zod had no way of discerning how important the relationship between  Clark and Lois was at that point, but he could have easily figured out there was something going on between them, just by seeing them bid each other farewell when his ship descended to retrieve Superman.

Answer (score 13):

Zod still thought that the "codex" was out there somewhere, and so it stands to reason that he brought Lois in case extreme measures were needed to force Kal-El to reveal its location. Later Zod learns

> that the codex is now fused with Kal-El, and when he does learn this, he simply asks his scientist something like, "Does Kal-El have to be alive for us to retrieve the codex?" (sorry, I can't remember exactly how he puts that).

Comment: Spoilers can be added using the `>!` notation and ended with a blank line.

Answer (score 5):

My impression is "because he wanted to hurt Jor-El's son".

The blogger mentioned that Lois Lane knows Kal-El's identity and she was next to Kal-El in front of the barricade, so Zod rightly concludes that is she is someone close to Kal-El and thus someone who he could hurt in order to hurt and/or coerce Kal-El.

Answer (score -1):

She is the only person who knows that he is Clark Kent. They read her mind and find out where the Kent's live and then go there to attempt to locate the codec

Comment: This was already covered in the accepted answer from July 2013.